# Regex htaccess help spam

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi I am really being bothered because of a hacker that got my google reference up to `6000` files that do not exist and because of the `404` reference page my bandwidth goes through the roof.

`90%` of the urls have the following structure:

```
/3592f6481003-124257

/378ca1044909-15695048

/02feab024511-7322687

/d26d46465210-13855220
```

Can someone help me with a `htaccess 410 RewriteRule`? I tried with matching more than 5 numbers in a row, but a lot of the minified css cache uses numbers too.

I think recognizing numbers+dash+numbers would do the trick

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your examples, you can use `[a-f0-9]+-[0-9]+`, i.e.:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^[a-f0-9]+-[0-9]+$ - [NC,R=410,L]
```

---

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cAt6uN/1)

---

[image]